# The population of a certain bacteria can multiply threefold in 24 hours. If there are 500 bacteria now, how many will there be in 96 hours?

Tags: calculus

The population of a certain bacteria can multiply threefold in 24 hours. If there are 500 bacteria now, how many will there be in 96 hours?

I figured out this bacteria $=500(3)^{96/24}$

but then my mate told me it's bacteria $=500(1+3/1)^{96/24 }$

what do I do what is the next step.

Comment: Your interpretation is the normal one.

Comment: Why is there a bounty on this question? The OP already has the answer, and the answers below debate the fine points of the problem statement (to a pretty strong conclusion). What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the intended meaning of *multiply threefold*. You’re interpreting it as meaning *increase by a factor of* $3$, which is how I would interpret it. Your mate is interpreting it to mean that the amount by which the population increases is $3$ times the present population; I would call that a fourfold increase. However, I can imagine someone using the term *multiply threefold* in that way; the only way to be certain what’s intended is to ask the person who set the problem.

Comment: Well that's the question... write from the book :( and I can't check my solutions... it sucks because I have to finish this course in 2 weeks and im stupid at it :(

Comment: @user73122: I’d go with your solution, with the population multiplying by $3$ every $24$ hours. I think that it’s more likely to be the right interpretation. Do you get to explain your answer, or do you just submit the number?

Comment: I need to explain it Brian do you have skype?

Comment: @user73122: I’m afraid not. But it’s good that you’re supposed to explain it: that means that even if your interpretation of the wording is wrong, the grader will see that the reasoning made sense. The explanation is no real problem: on your interpretation the population triples every $24$ hours. after one day it’s $500\cdot3$; after two days it’s $(500\cdot3)\cdot3=500\cdot3^2$; after three days its $(500\cdot3^2)\cdot3=500\cdot3^3$; and in general after $n$ days its $500\cdot3^n$. You know how many days there are in $96$ hours, so you know the right value of $n$ to use.

Answer (score 2):

Your mate is simply wrong. I see no ambiguity here at all.

Comment: It’s not nearly so common as the ambiguity in *three times more*, which for some of us natively means *four times as much*, not *three times as much*, but I’m pretty sure that I have encountered it in the wild. (Whether the OP’s mate actually has this usage or is simply applying the wrong formula is another question.)

Comment: I agree with TonyK that "multiply threefold" is not ambiguous.  "Increase threefold" is ambiguous, and it seems whoever posed the question was careful to avoid that.  If I were to criticize the formulation, it would be for "can multiply", which is intended to mean that the population not only can but in fact does multiply.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the ambiguity, that solution doesn't look right because that doesn't seem like the right rate constant. In order to solve an exponential growth problem we normally assume a growth given by
$$ P(t) = P(0) e ^{k t}$$
We can find k by using the given information (there is where the ambiguity lies, I agree that threefold prabably means 3 times the present value like the rest).
If we then use that 
$$P(24) = 3 P(0) = P(0) e ^{k 24}$$
we can then find k and the problem will be a little easier, since once we have k we can then find $P(t)$ for any future value of $t$.

Comment: at least when I do bacterial growth I normally use exponential models, just my 2 cents